# Consuming Sylius API through iOS

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, sylius

Currently I'm trying to consume sylius api using the domain demo.sylius.com, I've authenticated properly and got an access token with no problem but when it comes to passing the access token to the authorization header I ran into a problem with response `{
    error = "access_denied";
    "error_description" = "OAuth2 authentication required";
}` although the api works fine through postman , here's my sample code

```
func getTotalProducts(page:String, completionHandler: @escaping (_ totalProducts: TotalProducts) -> Void){
    let urlPath=APIManager.baseURL+"api/v2/products"
    let headers = ["Content-Type":"application/json","Authorization":"Bearer \(token)","X-Authorization":"Bearer SampleToken","Auth":"Bearer SampleToken","auth":"Bearer SampleToken"]
    var request = URLRequest(url:  NSURL(string: urlPath)! as URL)

    // Your request method type Get or post etc according to your requirement
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    request.setValue("Bearer SampleToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("Bearer SampleToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Authorization")
    request.setValue("Bearer SampleToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "auth")

    Alamofire.request(request)
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch(response.result){
            case .success(let value):
                print(value)
                let totalProducts = Mapper<TotalProducts>().map(JSON: value as! [String : Any])!
                completionHandler(totalProducts)
                break
            case .failure(let error):
                print("something went wrong \(error.localizedDescription)")
                break
            }
        }.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
request.setValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

Remove the following code:

```
//request.setValue("Bearer SampleToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Authorization")
//request.setValue("Bearer SampleToken", forHTTPHeaderField: "auth")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer but nothing works, please keep in mind that this is the request you can use it for postman, you can use the exact value "Bearer SampleToken" and application/json for Content-Type for the authorization header [https://demo.sylius.com/api/v2/products]